# Dynamic Links and Hosting disagreeing about whether the custom domain is properly connected or not

Tags: firebase, dns, firebase-hosting, firebase-dynamic-links

I am trying to use custom domain for dynamic links in my firebase project.

I opened dynamic links section in the firebase console and followed the instructions to add custom domain. After completing the DNS settings and waited for about few hours, firebase hosting page showed me that the custom domain was connected and when I access the root of the custom domain, it took me here:

[image: hosting website]

Here are my hosting console and dynamic links console page:

[image: hosting]

[image: dynamic links]

What am I missing here to get done with connecting custom domain to dynamic links and get started? How can hosting say it is connected and dynamic links say it is not?

Comment: I'm also having the same issue... any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the following answer from google support:
Thanks for reaching out. I'm happy to help you with your Dynamic Links issue.
I've checked your your Hosting configuration and it seems like it is properly configured. We're receiving similar reports regarding this, and our engineers are currently investigating the cause.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm relieved to hear that this was a problem on their end and not mine.

Comment: Got an update from Firebase support - this is now fixed!

Answer (score 2):

The error suddenly disappeared after almost 8 hours... but now it's back again.

Until Google fixes it, there is a **sneaky** workaround!

[https://console.firebase.google.com/u/1/project/{project_name}/durablelinks/creation/https:~2F~2F{custom-domain}](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/1/project/%7Bproject_name%7D/durablelinks/creation/https:%7E2F%7E2F%7Bcustom-domain%7D)

Note: You can only create a link though as everything else remains disabled.

**Updated 22/7/20: This is now fixed.**

Comment: Thank you. I'm relieved to hear that this is a problem on their end and not mine.

Comment: No problem! Me and @Michael Yavorovsky just got a response from Firebase saying it is fixed, but still seems to be the same. You had any luck?

Comment: Actually, no lock on my end either. I gave up and just created one with page.link domain...